How to delay fsync operations with cgroups_v2? Tried io.max and io.latency both have problems
I am trying to delay the fsync operations of a specific PID with c_groupsv2. After reading the documentation of cgroups it seems there are two possible ways:
Use io.max and set wops and rops to 0 during an interval, according to the limits documentation this should be possible. However, the kernel does not accept 0 as a value and outputs the ean error.
command: echo "259:0 wiops=0" > io.max
error_message: -bash: echo: write error: Numerical result out of range
Or use io.latency which is a cleaner solution, but this controller does not appear when I create a cgroup.
My question is two folded, first are there other options in terms of controllers, or other kernel based solutions for this?
Secondly, in terms of the problems I have with both io.max and io.latency is it something I am doing wrong? Is there something I have to enable?
Thanks in advance!

What does it mean to "delay fsync operations"? If the user calls fsync, he calls fsync. he kernel does not accept 0 so set it to 1

Delay "fsync operations" means when an application calls fsync it will take an extra amount of time(delay) to return. The idea behind setting wiops to 0 is to delay the fsync since wiops can not happen.

When an application calls fsync() function or fsync system call? You could get away with LD_PRELOAD for fsync() function. With fsync system call, I think only FUSE filesystem. It is highly unusual, while the rest of the world tries to make disc operations as fast as possible, you want to delay. Why?

Either, LD_PRELOAD does not work for static-linked languages like go, which is the language of the application I want to do this in. FUSE is an option but due to the properties of the research tool I am developing, I can not use it. As I previously mentioned research related not system development.
